# Append text to first line not containing a pattern?

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I want to use a Unix command such as `sed` or `awk` to append the string `"#DONE"` to the end of the first line in a text file not already containing the string `"#DONE"`.

For example the input file would be something like

```
qsub job1.sh #DONE
qsub job2.sh #DONE
qsub job3.sh 
qsub job4.sh
```

and the desired output would be

```
qsub job1.sh #DONE
qsub job2.sh #DONE
qsub job3.sh #DONE
qsub job4.sh
```

I am not experienced with this type of scripting, and I've searched but can't find the exact solution for this on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`Awk`** approach:

```
awk '!f && !/#DONE$/{ $0=$0 "#DONE"; f=1 }1' file
```

The output:

```
qsub job1.sh #DONE
qsub job2.sh #DONE
qsub job3.sh #DONE
qsub job4.sh
```

Comment: Ok yours is way better :-) but the `"#DONE";` should be `" #DONE";` I think and the file needs to be updated `>tmp && mv tmp "file"` or so

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/#DONE$/!{s/$/#DONE/;:a;n;ba}' file
```

Append `#DONE` to first line that does not have it, then print the remainder of the file.

Answer (score 2):

another `awk`

```
awk -v k="#DONE" '$NF!=k && !c++{$++NF=k}1' file
```

`!c++` will ensure it will be done only once, `$++NF=k` increments the number of fields and sets the last field to the value.

Answer (score 0):

pipe aproach where `file` is your file (place twice)

```
grep -nrv -m1 "#DONE" "file" | awk -F  ":" '{print $2}' | xargs -I {}  awk 'FNR=={},FNR=={}{$3="#DONE"};1' "$1" >tmp && mv tmp "file"
```

This will work as long as you are not completely #DONE.

If that happends the file will be emptied :-)

haven't figured that one out yet